# Can I override a method from a subscriber from third party bundle in PHP?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm adding KnpBehaviors Translations to my `Symfony` project. But I get an error when I want to set up a translation for one of my entities :

`` Column name `id` referenced for relation from Entity\EntityToBeTranslatedTranslation towards Entity\EntityToBeTranslated ``

In fact, it seems that in order to be translated, knp translations only work with Entity that has no custom name on Id. I would like to keep this custom name.

The method that gets the Id is in a Subscriber from knp : `Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Translatable\TranslatableSubscriber, in 'mapTranslation' method`

```
if (!$classMetadata->hasAssociation('translatable')) {
    $classMetadata->mapManyToOne([
        'fieldName'    => 'translatable',
        'inversedBy'   => 'translations',
        'cascade'      => ['persist', 'merge'],
        'fetch'        => $this->translationFetchMode,
        'joinColumns'  => [[
            'name'                 => 'translatable_id',
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'onDelete'             => 'CASCADE'
        ]],
        'targetEntity' => $classMetadata->getReflectionClass()->getMethod('getTranslatableEntityClass')->invoke(null),
    ]);
}
```

I would like to know if there is some way to override this method from this 3rd party bundle.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to [decorate the original subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) and then write your own logic instead.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to only override one method, keep the logic of the old subscriber and make it call the new method ? I tried to pass the old subscriber to the new in `arguments`, but without success

Comment: Yes, but you will have to still use decoration. When decorating the original listener you can pass it in into the overwriting listener by using the `__name__.inner` (see the linked docs). Now in your `OverwritingListener` you can just pass all calls to the decorated listener, but you will still have to write the methods. Here is a reference from another project (Doctrine ORM), where the EntityManager can be decorated and all existing methods from the original are called from the decorated service: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Decorator/EntityManagerDecorator.php

Comment: Thank you for your help, I managed to implement my own subscriber.